# Recordar valor input javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo un input para buscar un producto. Estoy intentando dejar las palabras escritas cuando den clic al enlace del producto y después den clic a un botón para regresar a esa búsqueda.

En término simple, recordar esa búsqueda.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
$("#keyword_text").on("keypress",function(e){
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#search_keywords").val($("#keyword_text").val());
        $("#btn_seach_product").trigger('click');   
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Recordar esa busqueda para siempre?, temporalmente?, mientras este en esa vista?, aclara tu pregunta

Comment: puedes guardar el texto del imput en una variable de session.

Comment: Puedes mostrar la información del producto en una pestaña nueva y el botón regresar a la búsqueda lo que haría es cerrar la pestaña recién abierta. Otra opción es, si la información del producto es poca, puedes presentarla en un `div` y el botón eliminaría la información del `div`... En fin, posibilidades hay muchas.

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien, pueden ser dos opciones:

la primera seria que en el input incluya el atributo:

```
autocomplete="on"
```

Con esto el input guardaría lo ultimo que se ha escrito, tambien podría ya lo otro seria con JavaScript pasar como parámetro por url el dato de la búsqueda